# On the singular locus of a normal ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a normal Noetherian ring. Then will the singular locus of $A$, i.e., $\{\mathcal{p}\in Spec(A)|A_{\mathcal{p}}\ \text{is not a regular ring}\} $, be  closed in $Spec(A)$? If so, what will be the ideal defining it and what can be said about the height of that ideal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is certainly true for affine algebras over a field, without even the hypothesis on normality. If you assume normal, then the height of the ideal defining the singular locus is at least two, which is the best you can say in general.

Comment: @Mohan:Thanks! Could you please hint the proof ?

Comment: Essentially follows from the Jacobian criterion of non-singularity.

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, thanks, I understand. But I don't want to take finitely generated $k$-algebra but rather can there be some condition on a Noetherian ring that we can impose so that the singular locus is closed ?

Comment: @Mohan is there some simple proof?I only know there is a proof in Hartshorne.But I don't understand.Thanks.

Comment: @Sky I do not know a simpler proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is worthwhile to point out that the singular locus is not always closed, even for normal domains:

**Theorem** [[Abhyankar and Heinzer 1988](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(91)90273-B), Thm. 6.3]**.** *There exists a two-dimensional normal noetherian domain, all of whose localizations at prime ideals are excellent, but whose singular locus is not closed.*

There are also local examples. Nishimura attributes the following to [Brodmann and Rotthaus](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(82)90046-1).

**Theorem** [[Nishimura 2012](https://doi.org/10.1215/21562261-1503754), Ex. 2.11]**.** *There exists a three-dimensional normal noetherian local domain, which is a complete intersection and universally Japanese, but whose singular locus is not closed.*

The condition that the singular locus is closed is called *J-1*. Affine algebras over a field are excellent, hence J-1 (pretty much by definition), so there is no conflict between these examples and [Mohan's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768004/on-the-singular-locus-of-a-normal-ring#comment5708467_2768004).